# Wrapping multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `div`s with two class name `k-edit-label` and `k-edit-feild`, which i need to wrap within in one class with name `wrapper`. How can I wrap the following `div`s.

HTML:

```html
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="personType"></div>
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="personStyle"></div>
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="title"></div>
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="firstName"></div>

<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="middleName"></div>
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="lastName"></div>
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="fatherName"></div>
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="spouseName"></div>

<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="dob"></div>
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="occupation"></div>
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="languagesKnown"></div>
<div class="k-edit-label"></div>
<div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="urLoginName"></div>
```

into like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="personType"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="personStyle"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="title"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="firstName"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="middleName"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="lastName"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="fatherName"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="spouseName"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="dob"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="occupation"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="languagesKnown"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-label"></div>
  <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="urLoginName"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried by using this:

```js
$('.k-edit-field:nth-child(4n)').each(function(index) {
  $(this).prevAll('.k-edit-field').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
});

$('.k-edit-form-container > .k-edit-field').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

but its not working because of multiple class name inside the divs.

Comment: You wrote `.k-edit-feild` instead of `.k-edit-field` in `$(this).prevAll('.k-edit-feild').andSelf()...`
Is it just a typo on stack or on your code too?

Comment: I would recommend to change your HTML 5 markup if possible and add some few more classes to create the groups you want.

Comment: @CyrilF Sorry for typo, I have edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('.k-edit-label:nth-child(8n+1)').each(function(i){
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(7)').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"/>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g3K63/)